# Download byte[] from the sqlite database and convert to a photo

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a problem with converting byte [] from the SQLITE database to the photo.

```
public List<Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>> GetNameAndImagesPositions()
        {
            sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(conn);
            sqlite_conn.Open();

            sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME, IMG_BALCONY, IMG_CROSS FROM MAIN";
            sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>> res = new List<Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>>();

            while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
            {
                Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>> tup = new Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>(sqlite_datareader.GetString(0),
                            new Tuple<byte[], byte[]>(
                                (byte[])sqlite_datareader["IMG_BALCONY"],
                                (byte[])sqlite_datareader["IMG_CROSS"]));
                res.Add(tup);
            }

            sqlite_conn.Close();

            return res;
        }
```

In the database, the photo (byte []) is stored in the BLOB.

```
DatabasePositions dbp = new DatabasePositions();
            List<Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>> list = new List<Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>>();
            list = dbp.GetNameAndImagesPositions();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var elm in list)
                {
                    string nameFile1 = elm.Item1 + "(1)";
                    string nameFile2 = elm.Item1 + "(2)";

                    Uri pat = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\report\\img\\" + nameFile1 + ".png");
                    using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(pat.LocalPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        var ms = new MemoryStream(elm.Item2.Item1);
                        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ms));
                        encoder.Save(outStream);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Error: in line `encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ms));`

```
System.NotSupportedException: "The appropriate image processing component needed to perform this operation was not found
```

I suspect that there is something wrong with converting byte [] from the database. The reason for this is that byte [] before working in the database works properly, but after downloading from the database no longer.

Comment: You are using `Tuple<string, Tuple<byte[], byte[]>>`,  why not to create some class with that structure?

Comment: Does every photo fail?

Comment: @L0uis For everyone from the database. When I apply the directly obtained byte [] it works properly.